# Windows client for Bonobo git server

Tags: windows, git, client, bonobo

Is there a working client for [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/) like [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)?
Anyone install and configure it?

Answer (score 3):

[Github](https://desktop.github.com/) & [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) would do just fine. It is just a Git server just like any other.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm finding a local and private git solution.